# Getting peculiar results while working with "[ ]" in egrep though "\"(escape sequence) used in Linux

Tags: regex, grep

Recently I came across below situation while doing some home work with regular expressions.

```
s@ubuntu:~$ echo b | egrep []b]
b
s@ubuntu:~$ echo b | egrep [[b]
b
s@ubuntu:~$ echo b | egrep []b[]
b
s@ubuntu:~$ echo b | egrep [b[]
b
s@ubuntu:~$ echo b | egrep [[b]]
s@ubuntu:~$ echo b | egrep [b]]
s@ubuntu:~$ echo b | egrep [b\]]
s@ubuntu:~$ echo b | egrep [b\\]]
s@ubuntu:~$ echo b | egrep [\[b\]]
```

Why I'm not getting 'b' printed in last 5 cases?

Comment: good question and why echo ba | egrep "[b\\c]" , give ba

Comment: It does print 'ba' but 'b' is highlighted and 'a' is printed as normal . It only matches the required character or string with highlighting it. In my system I got a red colored 'b' and a white colored 'a' @dacrovinunghi

Comment: @dacrovinunghi: `echo ba | egrep "[b\\c]"` selects `ba` because the character class matches a `b`, or a backslash, or a `c`, and the input contains a `b`.

Comment: ha yes give back the entiere line. ogrep not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is in the special rules applied inside the bracket expressions:

> The right square bracket`]` have to be placed immediately after the opening `[` or `[^` to be treated as a literal.

and

> An escape char `\` is treated literally inside a chars class `[...]`

In addiction the shell apply the escape char `\` prior to pass the expression to `egrep`, because of the missing single `'...'` or double quotes `"..."` around the regex.

Jonathan Leffler explain it well with examples, i can only report a link to the Posix rules of expansions inside brackets to add an overview:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05

**UPDATE**

The same expressions with quotes:

```
# this matches 'b]' or '\]'
~$ echo b] | egrep '[b\]]'
b]
~$ echo '\]' | egrep '[b\]]' # note the quotes prior and after the pipe
\]

# the next one is equivalent to '[b\]]' 
# cause a double \ inside chars class is redundant
~$ echo b] | egrep '[b\\]]'
b]
~$ echo '\]' | egrep '[b\\]]'
\]

# the last one matches '\]' or '[]' or 'b]'
~$ echo b] | egrep '[\[b\]]'
[b]
~$ echo [] | egrep '[\[b\]]'
[]
~$ echo '\]' | egrep '[\[b\]]'
\]
# without quotes in the echo section, the escape \ is applied by the shell
# so egrep receive only a closing bracket ']' and nothing is printed out
~$ echo \] | egrep '[\[b\]]'

# If we remove instead the quotes from the egrep section 
# the regex becomes equivalent to [[b]] so it now matches '[]' or 'b]' and not '\]' anymore
~$ echo '\]' | egrep [\[b\]]
~$ echo '[]' | egrep [\[b\]]
[] 
~$ echo 'b]' | egrep [\[b\]]
b]
```

Comment: I tried the above example with " "(double quotes). Still getting the same results. Could you please elaborate your idea behind explaining about applying " " or ' '.

Answer (score 5):

- `egrep [[b]]` — Looks for a `b` or `[` followed by a `]`; not found.
- `egrep [b]]` — Looks for a `b` followed by a `]`; not found.
- `egrep [b\]]` — Looks for a `b` followed by a `]`; not found.  The backslash is omitted by the shell and not seen by `egrep`.
- `egrep [b\\]]` — Looks for a `b` or a backslash followed by `]`; not found.
- `egrep [\[b\]]` — Looks for a `b` or a `[` followed by `]`; not found.  The backslashes are omitted by the shell and not seen by `egrep`.

Inside a character class (started by `[`), the first `]` terminates the class unless the `]` is the first character after the `[`, or the first character after the `[^` for a negated character class.  Note that `]` is not a regex metacharacter unless there is a preceding `[` making it into the end of a character class.  You also find that `$` is not a metacharacter in the middle of a string, nor `^` unless it appears at the start, nor `*` nor `+` nor `?` if they appear first, etc.  See POSIX [Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) for a detailed discussion — the regular expressions handled by `egrep` (now `grep -E`) are 'extended regular expressions'.

The shell messes around with backslashes before `egrep` gets a chance to see them.  You should enclose your regex in single quotes to avoid the shell altering what `egrep` sees.

You can demonstrate my analysis by changing what is echoed:

```
echo '[b]' | egrep [[b]]
echo '[b]' | egrep [b]]
echo '[b]' | egrep [b\]]
echo '[b]' | egrep [b\\]]
echo '[b]' | egrep [\[b\]]
```

The output from that is:

```
[b]
[b]
[b]
[b]
[b]
```

The `[` in these examples (in the echoed data) is present for cosmetic reasons; it could be omitted and the lines would be accepted.

Comment: You said -- egrep [b\\]] — Looks for a 'b' followed by a ']'. I doubt the word 'followed' used by you. As far as the shell messing thing is concerned I tried with " "(double quotes) but still in vain. @Jonathan

Comment: @SandeepSamal:  see the demonstration code. Experiment.  The argument passed by the shell to `egrep` is `[b]]`, which is interpreted as 'character class containing letter b followed by close square bracket', meaning that `b]` matches and nothing else does.

Comment: @SandeepSamal: you can see what `egrep` sees by using `printf "%s\n"` in its place.

Comment: The above answer helped me the most. Thanks. @Jonathan